# Vref circuit design for ADC/DAC

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-reference

I don't understand calculation and circuit design of external Vref circuits for ADCs/DACs (topic 13.7) in opamps for everyone design reference by Ron Mancini. How to be s=C2R2? How to be determined circuit component value? Please explain in detail.

[image]

Here is the example circuit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "s=C2R2" i.e. what do you mean by "s"?

Comment: Actually I don't understand which situations are proper for this circuit? (Opamp companzation) How to be select component values? I am not sure should I use or not for reference circuit?

Comment: What are you trying to understand how to do?

Comment: The circuit has a *zero* at \$ s = C_2 R_2\$ , as stated in the book. If you don't understand what 's' is and/or don't understand what a '*zero*' is, you have more (mathematical) homework to do.